# Handle slow callback functions when using x_range.on_change in Bokeh server

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

I'm trying to use callback functions to generate new data in a Bokeh server plot when the axis range changes. This works fine in principle: I've attached the necessary function to the plot using `p.x_range.on_change('end', my_callback_function)`, `my_callback_function` is executed and updates the plot.

The problem I'm facing is that the callback function can take a long time to complete. If the user pans the plot or zooms several steps while `my_callback_function` is still running, more `on_change` events are fired and new calls to `my_callback_function` pile up. This leads to the plot updating for a long time after the user has stopped panning or zooming.

Is there a way to cancel the execution of a callback function in case a new call is executed? Or is it possible to specify that only one call to a callback function may be queued up at any one time?

I tried deactivating the callback while the function is running by setting `p.x_range.remove_on_change('end', my_callback_function)` at the start of `my_callback_function`, but apparently that deactivation doesn't happen until the call to `my_callback_function` is complete: new calls are still piling up.

---

Here's a small example to play with: save it as `test.py` and execute it using `bokeh serve test.py --show`

```
import bokeh.plotting
import numpy
import time

def generate_data(start, end):
    time.sleep(1)
    newx = numpy.linspace(start + 0.1 * (end - start), end - 0.1 * (end - start), 10)
    newy = numpy.random.rand(10)
    return newx, newy

def my_callback_function(param, old, new):
    # I tried deactivating the callback once it's running...
    # p.x_range.remove_on_change('end', my_callback_function)
    x, y = generate_data(p.x_range.start, p.x_range.end)
    ds.data = {
        'x': x,
        'y': y
    }
    # ... and activating it again when done, but that doesn't work, the function calls still pile up
    # p.x_range.on_change('end', my_callback_function)

x, y = generate_data(0, 10)

p = bokeh.plotting.figure(x_range=[0, 10])
l = p.line(x, y)
ds = l.data_source

p.x_range.on_change('end', my_callback_function)

bokeh.plotting.curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Comment: This is something that will probably require new development. Can you make an issue on the Bokeh GH issue tracker to discuss things? In particular, your thoughts on how to spell things easily would be very valuable.

Comment: @bigreddot: [Done](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3702). Thanks for all your hard work, it's really appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I went through the github ticket, but I am not still quite sure how the `@gen.coroutine` and `@without_document_lock` should be implemented in this case. Can you help give an example of how the range callback would work now?